# ng-model won't evaluate dynamic array index

Tags: angularjs

My markup has a button that, on `ng-click`, `ng-include` template `info.html`. Since I expect the button click to happen lots of times, the `ng-include` is tied to a `ng-repeat` of the number of times the button is clicked — a counter variable on the scope:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="info">Info</label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">ADD</button>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="count in sum" ng-include="'info.html'"></div>
</div>
```

And here's `info.html`:

```
<div>
    <label for="attribute">Attribute</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.info[0].attribute" class="form-control">
    <label for="details">Details</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.info[0].details" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Basically `info.html` is a template for the entry of key, value pairs, and the user can enter as many key, value pairs as he so wishes. Here's the controller:

```
function($scope) {
    /** Tracks button clicks, the 1 is for the first
    set of key, value inputs to be shown when the form 
    is initially presented **/
    $scope.counter = 1; 

    // ng-model binding for the form inputs 
    $scope.form = {};

    // This is what will hold the key, value pairs (as objects).
    $scope.form.info = [];

    /** This array is for simply adding an entry whenever
    the button is clicked. I need this array for the ng-repeat **/
    $scope.sum = [];
    $scope.sum.push($scope.counter);

    for (var counter of $scope.sum) {
        // Make each element in $scope.form.info an object
        $scope.form.info[counter] = {};
    }

    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.counter++;
        $scope.sum.push($scope.counter);
    }
}
```

Now, notice that in `info.html`, `form.info[0].attribute` and `form.info[0].details` have the hardcoded value `0`. I want that value to be dynamic. I've tried

- -`form.info[$index + 1].attribute`

  -`form.info[{{$index +1}}].attribute`

  -`form.info[counter].attribute`

  -`form.info[{{counter}}].attribute`

But rather than getting a numerical value, I get the literal strings. As a last resort, I wrote a directive:

```
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var attribute = 'form.info[' + scope.counter + '].attribute';
            var details = 'form.info[' + scope.counter + '].details';
            if (attrs.info == 'attribute') {
                $(element).attr('ng-model', attribute);
                return;
            }
            if (attrs.info == 'details') {
                $(element).attr('ng-model', details);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then applied it (the directive's name is `info`)

```
<input type="text" info="attribute" class="form-control">
<input type="text" info="details" class="form-control">
```

This directive didn't work, either. The inputs did not get a two-way binding to `form.info`. And not only that, the classes `ng-pristine`, `ng-untouched`, `ng-valid`, etc were missing from those inputs.

So how do I get a result like

```
ng-model="form.info[0].attribute"
ng-model="form.info[0].details"
ng-model="form.info[1].attribute"
ng-model="form.info[1].details"
ng-model="form.info[2].attribute"
ng-model="form.info[2].details"
```

... and so on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using `counter` and `sum[]` for something else, just get rid of them. They're unnecessary for what you're trying to do here. Then in your `$scope.add()` function, add another object to the `scope.form.info[]` array.

```
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.form.info.push({});
}
```

Then change your `ng-repeat` to repeat over `form.info[]`...

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in form.info" ng-include="'info.html'"></div>
```

and bind directly to each object in the array...

```
<div>
    <label for="attribute">Attribute</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.attribute" class="form-control">
    <label for="details">Details</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.details" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, thank you. Accepted and upvoted.